cannot use ng select component in my angular application
In my angular application i was trying to use ng-select for showing drop downs. my angular version is 17 and it only supports ng select v12.
i use standalone components in my application , when i am trying to import ng-select component and declare it in the import array it shows "

error from '@ng-select/ng-select' The component 'NgSelectComponent' appears in 'imports', but is not standalone and cannot be imported directly. It must be imported via an NgModule..

import {NgSelectComponent} from '@ng-select/ng-select';
@Component({
 selector: 'app-service-edit',
 standalone: true,
 imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule,NgSelectComponent],
 templateUrl: './service-edit.component.html',
 styleUrl: './service-edit.component.css',
})
export class ServiceEditComponent {
}

and my html component is
<ng-select>
    @for (site of sites; track site.id){
       
        <option>{{site.name}}</option>
    }
</ng-select>

but my applicaion does not have an app module since i was following angular recommendation to use standalone components.
my package.json
  "name": "service-report-front",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^16.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^12.0.7",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}


please share package.json

@Naren Murali package.json added

You can read in the v12.0.7 docs that you need to import NgSelectModule. Only starting from v13, NgSelectComponent is a standalone component and can be added to the imports directly.
import {NgSelectModule} from '@ng-select/ng-select';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-service-edit',
 standalone: true,
 imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule, NgSelectModule],
 templateUrl: './service-edit.component.html',
 styleUrl: './service-edit.component.css',
})

